# using Jquery in selectbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectbox

Here is part of my HTML. This part will convert to a select box in small size 
Every `li` make a group , By click on each `li` members of groups will show, I used CSS filter for this .
My question is how to rearrange member by clicking on each `li` in selectbox

```
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="filter" data-filter="all">
                <a href="#noAction">evey item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="web">
                <a href="#noAction">web</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="photo">
                <a href="#noAction">photo</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="identity">
                <a href="#noAction">identity</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="news">
                <a href="#noAction">news</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amirhsh/0xtntxo6/
After selecting items in select box li depend on arrange

Comment: Can you please add html or add a fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle and providing extensive input is always a good idea so you don't get all these downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@amir, try the below code:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="filter" data-filter="all">
            <a href="#noAction">evey item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter="web">
            <a href="#noAction">web</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter="photo">
            <a href="#noAction">photo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter="identity">
            <a href="#noAction">identity</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter="news">
            <a href="#noAction">news</a>
        </li>
    </ul>


<div class="all web hide" > <p> some web contents </p> </div>
<div class="all news hide" > <p> some news contents </p> </div>
<div class="all photo hide" > <p> some photo contents </p> </div>
<div class="all news hide" > <p> some news contents </p> </div>
<div class="all photo hide " > <p> some photo contents </p> </div>
<div class="all web hide " > <p> some web contents </p> </div>
<div class="all identity hide" > <p> some identity contents </p>
<div class="all web hide" > <p> some web contents </p> </div>
<div class="all identity hide" > <p> some identity contents </p> 
<div class="all news hide" > <p> some news contents </p> </div>
<div class="all identity hide" > <p> some identity contents </p>
<div class="all web hide" > <p> some web contents </p> </div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

**JS CODE:**

```
 $("li").click(function(){
    $("div").hide();
     var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    alert(filter);

    $("div").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass(filter)) {
             $(this).show();   
        }

    }); 
});
```

Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: it didn't help completely but gave me  a clue!